# What should I do to fix Restore Purchases PaymentPendingError error?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing, revenuecat

Hi I am testing sandbox subscriptions with test user 5 min / month and 30 min/ year with Revenue Cat.
And I am also testing restore Purchase. But every time handle the same error

> PurchaseCode.PaymentPendingError

With debug I see that

`billingWrapper.queryAllPurchases` return the list of purchases, but next
return the list of `PurchaseWrapper objects`

```
PurchaseWrapper(isConsumable=true, purchaseToken=blablalbla, purchaseTime=11111111, sku=blabla_subscription_year, containedPurchase=null, type=SUBS, presentedOfferingIdentifier=null)
```

But, 
`containedPurchase==null` 
and that's why i get the erro after check has failed:

```
 if (purchase.containedPurchase?.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED)
```

What should I do to solve the issue?

regards,
Serg

Answer (score 2):

It works!
I should to update version from  'com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases:3.0.2' to 
 'com.revenuecat.purchases:purchases:3.0.4'

Comment: There was a bug in 3.0.2 that broke `restorePurchases`. It got fixed in 3.0.3. Glad you figured it out.